# which live usb support ryzen gen 2 and x570 with intel wifi 6?

Tags: live-usb

I'm trying to find which live usb would support the new ryzen gen2 cpu / chipset x570 and the intel wifi 6 (mostly, gigabyte aorus x570 pro wifi)

most current distribution (for what i read) have issue, I don't want to download multiple ISO if someone already know which one would work

Answer (score 0):

I have built a pc using the Gigabyte Aorus Ultra mb with all of those features. Went through several distros before coming upon MX Linux. While it still initially has the same issues as all the others (the kernel won't support the intel wifi 6), it was the easiest by far to update the kernel (to anything after 5.1)(they have the 5.2 in the test repo of their package manager) then install the newer iwlwifi microcode provided by Intel. MX Linux also has a nice feature that allows you to make a snapshot of your os (1.5 minutes) and make a bootable usb (another 10-15 minutes) which is capable of persistence (so any changes you make while booted on the usb are saved to it). Have been using that alot. As I am new to Linux, as I tweak it I create the snapshots, then when I break it I can reinstall to the last snapshot instead of starting all over again. Hope this helps.